# Fetch Weekly Data By Query in Sql Server

Tags: asp.net

i have a table Which  name is 'Emp_Attendance_New' who kept record of emp attendance.when i fire a query like this who  give particular result.

Query:

```
Select Atendencedate ,Emp_Id,Attendance_Status ,EmpName  
from  Emp_Attendance_New  where Emp_Id ='20140160' 
and  Atendencedate between '3/30/2015' and '4/5/2015'
```

Result:

```
Atendencedate   Emp_Id     Attendance_Status     EmpName
2015-03-30  20140160    P           Vikash Prasad
2015-03-31  20140160    P           Vikash Prasad
2015-04-01  20140160    P           Vikash Prasad
2015-04-02  20140160    P           Vikash Prasad
2015-04-03  20140160    P           Vikash Prasad
2015-04-04  20140160    P           Vikash Prasad
```

but i want only  the result in only single row  like this:

```
Emp_Id      EmpName        2015-03-30    2015-03-31  2015-04-01   2015-04-02   
2014016   Vikash Prasad       P            P            P           P
```

Comment: The rules are not clear. Which `Attendance_Statuses` are possible and what do you want to show if there is no record for a particular date in this range? Since this is not related to ASP.NET but sql you should remove that tag but add the rdbms.

Comment: I think this will help you https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/switching-rows-and-columns-in-sql/